# Is the Darboux approach / definition compatible with a bounded integrator in Riemann–Stieltjes integrals? Why these hypothesis in Rudin PMA chapter 6?

Tags: integration, stieltjes-integral

I'm reading Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis $6^{th}$ chapter and am wondering why doesn't he require the weaker condition of $\alpha$ (the integrator) being bounded on $[a,b]$ ?

Is he doing that just to simplify things ? Or is there an incompatibility between his definition of the Riemann–Stieltjes integral (he uses the definition with *Upper and Lower integrals*) and the weaker condition of $\alpha$ being bounded on $[a,b]$ ?

I was thinking of this possibility that maybe the *Upper and Lower integrals approach* is only compatible with the monotonically increasing integrators $\alpha$.

Comment: If you have a function of bounded variation then you can express it as a difference of two monotone functions, so using just monotone functions for the integrator is simpler and it’s not a loss of generality.

Comment: Oh ok. But Apostol's book says $\alpha$ must be bounded on $[a,b]$. Being bounded is not equivalent to being of bounded variation? In fact, it's a weaker condition.